# React.js - Deploying site on Netlify or Firebase - Missing CSS file

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I want to ask you did you have problem with deploying your site on Firebase or Netlify and then finding out that a CSS file is actually missing. What I mean by that. Well on localhost everything is working perfectly just like I want to, but when I deploy my "page" on these hosting services it just doesnt show correctly the way it is shown on localhost (the design is completely off)

Did you have problems with this? Is my webpack not working or what. I used create-react-app to create my React.js website.

Comment: Can you provide some more context. What's your Netlify deploy command and what's the output directory. If you haven't modified any of the default react scripts or the default netlify commands it should work out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what is my issue. I left a semi-colon at the end of CSS file, and that is why it wasn't parsed properly